# Upgrade Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012, failover cluster problems?

Tags: windows-server-2012, failovercluster

I have a 2-node failover cluster for testing some of our Hyper-V automation Powershell scripts. I evicted node 2, so that I could run the upgrade to Server 2012 Datacenter. The upgrade seems to have executed OK. Now when I log into node 2, I can no longer do "ipmo failoverclusters" in powershell. I can also no longer locate Failover Cluster Manager.

When I launch Server Manager, I can see that Failover Clustering is listed as a feature in my Roles and Features list on the local server (ie. node 2).

Is there something I might be missing in my setup? I haven't activated windows yet since the upgrade, could that be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if I select the Local Server in the server manager, scroll down to the Features list, right click on FailoverClusters and Edit/Remove, it will then allow me to uncheck it. If I uncheck it and remove it, and then re-add the feature, I get the correct version of FailoverClusters and it seems to be working correctly.

This was just a little confusing because I couldn't uncheck the feature directly from the Add/Remove Features area in control panel. Perhaps as suggested, that was a permissions thing.

Answer (score 0):

After you evict the node you'll probably want to uninstall Failover Clustering then do the upgrade then install Failover Clustering again.  At this point I'd try uninstalling Failover Clustering then reinstall it.  As there's no way to upgrade a cluster they probably don't put much support behind upgrading a machine that has the Failover Cluster features installed.

Comment: In the Add Roles and Features wizard, I tried to uncheck "Failover Clustering (Installed)", but it is greyed out. Could that be a permissions problem, or is there something else I should examine first?

Comment: That could be permissions. Are you a local admin on the server?